Intuition for sections of projective bundles and associated quotients
We work over ${\mathbb C}$. Let $Y$ be a smooth projective variety, and let $\mathcal{E}$ be a locally free sheaf of rank $r$ over $Y$. Define $X:= \mathbb{P}_Y(\mathcal{E})$ to be the projective bundle over $Y$ (following Hartshorne's book notation), with projection map $\pi:X\to Y$.
I know that sections $s:Y\to X$ of $\pi$ are in correspondence with quotient invertible sheaves $\mathcal{E}\to \mathcal{L}\to 0$. This suggests me that the quotient invertible sheaf $\mathcal{L}$ tells something about the image of section $s$, and I would like to understand it with explicit examples.
For istance, suppose I have that I have the following quotients:

$\mathcal{E}\to \mathcal{O}_Y\to 0$
$\mathcal{E}\to \mathcal{O}_Y(1)\to 0$
$\mathcal{E}\to \mathcal{O}_Y(-1)\to 0$

I would expect that these quotients give rise to different sections. Is there a way to understand the geometry of the associated sections? I know I am being very vague, but I would like t develop some sort of intuition.
Edit: Thanks to Harthsorne, chap. II, exercise 7.8, I know that I obtain sections $s: Y\to X$ such that, in each of the above quotients, we get that:

$s^*\mathcal{O}_{X}(1)=\mathcal{O}_Y$
$s^*\mathcal{O}_X(1)=\mathcal{O}_Y(1)$
$s^*\mathcal{O}_X(1)=\mathcal{O}_Y(-1)$

My question thereforereally is: what geoemtric information of the section I can derive from these equalities? For instance, am I contracting the image of the section?

No, Harthshorne II, exercise 7.8 (this is a section, not a general morphism, thus $\pi\circ s$ is the identity map of $Y$.

@Daniel for example, take $Y$ to be a point, and $\cal E= \mathbb C^r$. Then, a la Grothendieck and the question above, the points of $\mathbb P^{r-1}(\mathbb C)$ 'can be identified' with the one-dimensional quotients of $\cal E$ (as opposed to lines in $\cal E$.)
